# How does composition work in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, code-behind, default-constructor

**I have a Car Class:**

```
public class Car
{    
    private String _Brand;
    private String _Model;
    private Engine _Engine;

    public Car(){

    }

     public String Brand
     {
        get { return _Brand; }
        set { _Brand = value; }
     }

     public String Model
     {
        get { return _Model; }
        set { _Model = value; }
     }

     public Engine Engine
     {
        get { return _Engine; }
        set { _Engine = value; }
     }
}
```

**And an Engine Class:**

```
public class Engine
{
     private int _Code;
     private DateTime _Year;

     public Engine(){

     }

     public int Code
     {
        get { return _Code; }
        set { _Code = value; }
     }

     public DateTime Year
     {
        get { return _Year; }
        set { _Year = value; }
     }
}
```

From code-behind of **Registration.aspx.cs**, I wanna create using a button, a Car and an Engine w/ theirs respective relationship (Composition).

However, I have a massive confusion about how a composition for these objects should be behave. I.E., I can't figure it out if I must declare: `Engine = new Engine();` in Car's constructor or if in Registration Event (Button, Code-Behind) declare: `Car car = new Car()` and then `car.Engine = new Engine();`.

I don't how composition relationship work in a scenario like this. The existence of where to declare "`new`" is putting me in a mixing of concepts.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor a bit your classes like below, in order to avoid [boilerplate code](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d0e913/lame-question-of-the-day-what-is-boilerplate-code/). We just use a feature called *auto implement properties*.

```
public class Engine
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{    
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Engine Engine {get; set; } 
}
```

Please notice now how many lines of codes have been removed.

Regarding your question, you could create an object of type `Car` using an *object initializer* like below:

```
var car = new Car 
{
    Brand = "the brand name";
    Model = "the model name";
    Engine = new Engine
    {
        Code = "the code engine";
        Year = new DateTime(2017,1,1); // the year the engine manufactured.
    }
}
```

I would suggest you read about both of these features, *auto implemented properties* and *object initializers*. Below, there are two links about these features.

- [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)
- [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: This doesn't explain what a Composition between Car and Engine is, neither why Composition wouldn't be the best choice for this particular problem.

Comment: @DesertFox I didn't mention the concept of *composition* at all, because I think that the OP problem actually is not what is composition and how this is implemented in C#, but how you instantiate an object of a custom type, which has as a property of another custom type.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years I've discussed this level of class architecture, so I'll try no to sound stupid :)

To begin with, I don't think we are talking Composition here: (in real life) the lifecycle of an `Engine` is not tied/controlled by a `Car`. If I'm assuming correctly, both classes are trying to represent a mapping of real life.

As far as I'm aware, in real, you can purchase an `Engine` to a `Car`, but a `Car` cannot function (but can exist) without an `Engine` (maybe those new fancy Teslas can?).

That screams is not a Composition since doesn't describe a relationship of ownership.

Depending on how strict you want to be, I'd call that an Aggregation (more) or an Association (less).

I personally would tend more towards the Aggregation because is a stronger relationship than, let's say, a `Car` and a `Spoiler`.

So, for that, my suggestion would be:

**C#**

```
public class Engine
{
     public Engine() { ... }     

     public int Code { get; set; }

     public DateTime Year { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
     public Car(Engine engine) : this() { 
          this.Engine = engine;
     }

     public Car() {
     } 

     public string Brand { get; set; }

     public String Model { get; set; }

     public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}
```

**Codebehind**

```
var engine = new Engine();
var car = new Car(engine);
```

That `Car` class definition is saying you can create a `Car` with or without an `Engine`, but for me it stresses the fact that an `Engine` is indeed important to a `Car` so a constructor accepting an `Engine` is available.

**About composition**

The composition of an `Car` being the "whole" and `Engine` being a "part" means that the `Engine` lifecycle is completely controlled by the `Car`. In this case, you are basically stating that "Upon the creation of a new object of Car, that object will internally create a new Engine which will be disposed when the Car object is no longer used."

The code for that would look like this:

```
//still the same
public class Engine
{
     public Engine() { ... }     

     public int Code { get; set; }

     public DateTime Year { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
     public Car() {
        //_engine = new Engine();
     }

     //Engine initialisation can be either here or inside the constructor (check constructor's commented code)
     private readonly Engine _engine = new Engine();

     public string Brand { get; set; }

     public String Model { get; set; }

     //you shouldn't be able to assign an _engine from outside
     public Engine Engine { get { return _engine; } }
}
```

**Composition Code-behind**

```
var car = new Car();
car.Engine.Code = 123;
```

Comment: You're right. This is more like an aggregation than a composition, my bad. Regardless of the relationship between these two. My concern was about how to treat composition and where to declare a "new" by applying a composition correctly. The "new" of the class and the "new" of the code-behind mess my design. Yes, I know, is my fault.

Comment: So in Code-Behind (Speaking of composition). I shouldn't declare: Engine engine = new Engine(), instead I do a: Car car = new Car(); and below of it, Car.Engine.Brand = txtBrand.Text?.

Comment: Yes, in the composition case that is just fine.

Comment: no worries mate, happy to help (and revisit some concepts i used long ago). If you liked the answer, feel free to mark as the answer of you question/give an "up"

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the way you design your classes. Car and Engine are very generic. For instance, if you were to create a Mercedes, then it makes sense to create a new type, *MercedesCar* that inherits from the *Car*. In this case, you could instantiate a *MercedesEngine* from within the constructor of the *MercedesCar* as follows:

```
public class Car
{
    public Engine Engine
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Car(Engine engine)
    {
        this.Engine = engine;
    }
}

public class MercedesCar : Car
{
    public MercedesCar() : base(new MercedesEngine())
    {
    }
}

public class Engine
{
}

public class MercedesEngine : Engine
{
}
```

But if you were to stick with *Car* class alone, then there is nothing wrong in creating the engine from the outside!

Comment: Yes. I just used it as example (Not the best example by the way...) to clear this up. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you want the control the accessibility/use of the Engine property.

**Case 1:**
If you want Car to have full control of the Engine property and no one else to access it, make it a private field and instantiate inside the Car constructor.

```
public class Car
{
    private readonly Engine _engine;
    public Car()
    {
        _engine = new Engine();
    }               
}
```

**Case 2:**
Engine should be accessible from outside, such that anyone can set it or access it.
It can be done in 2 ways:

1) *Constructor Injection* - injecting the dependency via constructor, usually abstracted using an interface so that mocking/unit testing can be done easily.

```
public class Car
{
    public Car(IEngine engine)
    {
        Engine = engine;
    }
    public IEngine Engine { get; set; }
}
var car = new Car(new Engine());
```

2) *Setting Engine property manually*

```
public class Car
 {  
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }           
 }
var car = new Car();
car.Engine = new Engine();
```

Comment: But, if I instantiate it inside the Car constructor. Should I instantiate the Engine in the button event (Code-Behid)?.

Comment: You don't need to. Engine is private to car and will be taken care of by Car, when Car is instantiated.

Comment: Like this you say: Car.Engine.Code = txtCode.Text;?